# How to use Combine to tell when a Core Data object changed

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, combine

I just implemented multiple windows in my app and am having trouble checking when a core data item was updated in the window right next to it. It seems like Apple's Combine can fix this problem by adding a subscriber to the core data item to listen for changes, but all the documentation I'm finding on Combine is with SwiftUI and I'm using UIKit.

Can anyone help me add a subscriber to the core data item listen for any changes to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're only trying to get notified about one certain core data item at a time you may not even need Combine. Try using a notification.

I think this Apple Developer video will help: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/258/